# Microsoft IME switches to direct input when focusing on the search bar in Chrome?

Tags: discussion, ime

I don't remember it doing that before. Even if I do have it in kana, when I try to type into the browser it goes back to romaji. Was it always like this and I just imagined it not being like this? Or is this a recent change, and does anybody know how to fix this minor nuisance.

Comment: related: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/cannot-use-japanese-romaji-input-even-if-i-change/0b978f05-4be2-4ba9-a683-2ce947562daf

Comment: I had several other problems with Microsoft IME, I switched to google's and it's working perfectly.